# Jquery validation not getting correct language

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 project im using the `jquery.validate.js` lib and add some extension to change the language of the message displayed on validation. For this extension a wrote a file `messages_pt_BR.js` and put it in the `BundleConfig` file:

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/input_validade").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.mask.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/messages_pt_BR.js"
                    ));
```

All the files are loaded correctly, but the message still on validation still the same. `The x field must be a number.`. The extension in messages_pt_BR.js file:

```
$.extend( $.validator.messages, {
  required: "Este campo &eacute; requerido.",
remote: "Por favor, corrija este campo.",
email: "Por favor, forne&ccedil;a um endere&ccedil;o de email v&aacute;lido.",
url: "Por favor, forne&ccedil;a uma URL v&aacute;lida.",
date: "Por favor, forne&ccedil;a uma data v&aacute;lida.",
dateISO: "Por favor, forne&ccedil;a uma data v&aacute;lida (ISO).",
number: "Por favor, forne&ccedil;a um n&uacute;mero v&aacute;lido.",
digits: "Por favor, forne&ccedil;a somente d&iacute;gitos.",
creditcard: "Por favor, forne&ccedil;a um cart&atilde;o de cr&eacute;dito v&aacute;lido.",
equalTo: "Por favor, forne&ccedil;a o mesmo valor novamente.",
maxlength: $.validator.format( "Por favor, forne&ccedil;a n&atilde;o mais que {0} caracteres." ),
minlength: $.validator.format( "Por favor, forne&ccedil;a ao menos {0} caracteres." )

 } );
```

EDIT:
Scripts loaded:
[image: scripts]

Comment: Can it be that you have any other language files attached? Check `head` section of rendered html and show what to you have there.

Comment: no, i have just the portoguese file attached.

Answer (score 0):

Does console output error?
When I use the plugin, I will load jquery.js first,so the code will be like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js">
<script src="jquery.validate.js">
<script src="messages_es.js">
```

Comment: nothing in the console. And yes, jquery is loaded first but in another bundle.

Comment: or you just edit the jquery.validate.js?, it may not be the correct way, but I can't think of the best way.@ggui